# Celery beat runs every minute instead of every 15 minutes

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

I'm setting my celery to have the schedule

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'update_some_info': {
        'task': 'myapp.somepath.update_some_info',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/15'),
    },
}
```

when checking what's actually written in crontab, it's indeed `<crontab: */15 * * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>`

but my celery log indicates that the task is running every minute

```
INFO 2020-01-06 13:21:00,004 beat 29534 139876219189056 Scheduler: Sending due task update_some_info (myapp.somepath.update_some_info)
INFO 2020-01-06 13:22:00,003 beat 29534 139876219189056 Scheduler: Sending due task update_some_info (myapp.somepath.update_some_info)
INFO 2020-01-06 13:23:00,004 beat 29534 139876219189056 Scheduler: Sending due task update_some_info (myapp.somepath.update_some_info)
INFO 2020-01-06 13:24:28,255 beat 29534 139876219189056 Scheduler: Sending due task update_some_info (myapp.somepath.update_some_info)
```

Why isn't celery beat picking up my schedule?

Comment: It should be `*/15`.

Comment: sorry that was a typo. fixed